# How to install OData support in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, nuget, odata

MVC4 Web API in .NET 4 is used in Visual Studio Community Edition .

Web API controller which accepts OData query string should created.

Tutorial in

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#01-02-getting-started

recommends to add OData supoort using

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Odata`

I tried to install it using NuGet but got error

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any
assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Greatest version avaliable in NuGet is 5.7.0  and smallest 5.2.0

Both of them give this error.

How to install OData support in .NET 4 MVC4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to install OData for .NET 4, could you try run this [command](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/4.0.30506)?

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -Version 4.0.30506
```

That should install the following dependencies:

```
    Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.0.20710.0)
    Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 4.0.20710.0)
    Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 4.0.20710.0)
    Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.2.0)
```